# Overlap of a column based on a different column

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a simple table in Postgres that contains days of the week and people.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (day, person)
values
('Monday', 'A'),
('Monday', 'A'),
('Monday', 'B'),
('Tuesday', 'A'),
('Wednesday', 'A'),
('Wednesday', 'B'),
('Thursday', 'B'),
('Thursday', 'B');
```

I would like to find the number of overlapping people for each pair of days. So for example, Monday has Person A and B. Tuesday has person B only, so that would yield a row as follows:

```
('Monday', 'Tuesday', 1)
```

The final output should look like this:

```
('Monday', 'Monday', 2),
('Monday', 'Tuesday', 1),
('Monday', 'Wednesday', 2),
('Monday', 'Thursday', 1),
('Tuesday', 'Tuesday', 1),
('Tuesday', 'Monday', 1),
('Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 1),
('Tuesday', 'Thursday', 0),
('Wednesday', 'Wednesday', 2),
('Wednesday', 'Monday', 2),
('Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 1),
('Wednesday', 'Thursday', 1),
('Thursday', 'Thursday', 1),
('Thursday', 'Monday', 1),
('Thursday', 'Tuesday', 0),
('Thursday', 'Wednesday', 1)
```

I have been playing around with cross joins and intersect, but nothing seems to yield the correct result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a self  join:

```
select t1.day, t2.day, count(distinct t2.person) as num_overlaps
from mytable t1 join
     mytable t2
     on t1.person = t2.person
group by t1.day, t2.day
order by t1.day, t2.day;
```

EDIT:

I see you want to include zero overlaps as well.  This is a little trickier.  For this, you need to generate all combinations of days and then join in the data:

```
select d1.day, d2.day, count(distinct t2.person)
from (select distinct day from mytable) d1 cross join
     (select distinct day from mytable) d2 left join
     mytable t1
     on t1.day = d1.day left join
     mytable t2
     on t2.day = d2.day and t2.person = t1.person
group by d1.day, d2.day
order by d1.day, d2.day;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=878ae34cd05e517da72d7676b7932f89) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at the query and it's not yielding the right results. Could it be due to the people on a single day when you join on person?

Comment: @user2242044 . . . In the second query, the `=` for persons should be `<>`.

Comment: Thanks. I think you just need to have your left joins be `(select distinct * from mytable)` so we don't double count if a person appears twice on the same day. Or something similar. Doesn't seem quite right still.

Comment: Based on your comment, t2 is joined based on dissimilar persons, but it doesn't check to make sure the days share a similar one. I'm not sure I explained it well, but check out the Tuesday, Thursday. The query yields 1, but the results should yield 0.

Comment: @user2242044 . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  I think this works.